# Spring Boot 2.0 / OAuth2 / JWT / Zuul / Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to build a **microservice architecture**. But i'm **struggling** since two days **with OAuth2 and Zuul**. I managed to run a Auth/Resource-Server on the same service, but not with Zuul. At the moment i'm swichting to another service, the authorization doesn't work anymore. I t**ried many guides** (as an example Baeldung) but **no one works for me**. Probably because i'm using **Spring Boot 2.0.3**? **Most guides using Spring Boot 1.5.x**.

I think it's a **problem of configuration**. I'm using Eureka for service discovering, Zuul as Gateway and entry point. When the user request a protected service, he should be redirectet to my auth-service (OAuth2/JWT). **The token he gets after login should be stored by Zuul (right ?)**. Actually **Zuul doesn't get the token or doesn't store it**. Do I have to do this by my own or should Zuul and OAuth manage this and I just have bad configurations? Could someone show me, how you configure this architecture or a **new/working guide for Spring Boot 2.0.3?** I'm actually really frustrated, **need help**. I'm new to Spring, but have to learn it for work. But at the moment i'm just overstrained.

Additional infos:

I didnt create any views now. I just defined some default controller which return `String`s and are secured by `@PreAuthorize`.

**Gateway-Service:**

> GatewayServiceApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@Configuration
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/core/", "/core/login**", "/oauth/authorize", 
                 "/core/oauth/authorize", "/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Here I had a lot of different `antMatchers`.

> application.properties

```
server.port=8000
spring.application.name=gateway-service
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8001/eureka/
security.oauth2.sso.login-path=http://localhost:8000/core/login
security.oauth2.client.client-id=zuul
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=zuul
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:8000/core/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:8000/core/oauth/authorize
#security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8000/core/user/me
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8000/core/secured
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

I think here's a failure.

**Core-Service**

> CoreApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableResourceServer
public class CoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> AuthServerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(
            AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("zuul")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("zuul"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8000/core/secured");
    }
}
```

> SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("john")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("123"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

> application.properties

```
server.port=8003
spring.application.name=core
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8001/eureka
```

Ok, especially here I changed many things. So probably I destroyed much from older guides. (Sorry my english is bad!)

Comment: Hi, did you get it working? Facing similar issue.